# How to wrap the contents around an image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an about page for a personal website. I am wondering how to wrap the text around the picture. I want this kind of effect. http://alexbudak.com/about/

The code I have right now is:

```
 <div class="about_content">
            <img src="placeholder.jpg" alt="">
            <h2>The Brand</h2>
            </p>
            The Tailory New York is an appointment only custom clothing              company that combines the modernity of Fashion Design with the heritage art of Custom Tailoring. We are unique in that we cater to both the Men and Women market.
           </p>
            <h2>The Concept </h2>
                <p>
                    Providing personally designed, fitted and curated collections for each individual client is the essence of who we are. At The Tailory New York, we believe that your wardrobe should not only fit perfectly, but should be designed with only YOU in mind. The end result?—clients get the best of both worlds, impeccable custom fit and custom designed pieces that works seamlessly with their lifestyle.
                </p>
            <h2>A Note From the Founder</h2>
                <p>
                    The idea for The Tailory New York began when I decided to direct my years of fashion design and men’s tailoring experience towards my own wardrobe. As a pant suit aficionado and a lover of men’s fashion and tailoring, I was always drawn to tailored clothing and strived to create fashion that conveyed the same message of confidence that a perfectly custom tailored suit did for men. Style icons like Sean Connery and Cary Grant, as well as modern day 007 Daniel Craig (shaken not stirred) were always my style inspirations. To me, they are the epitome of refinement and sophistication, true gentlemen in style.
                    My passion for fashion and tailoring led me through the Fashion Design program at Parsons followed by stints in custom tailoring, fashion design, fashion styling and brand development. But the more I integrated myself in the industry, the more I realized that impeccable fit, for men and women, was almost impossible to find in ready to wear clothing. So, I launched The Tailory New York, a way for me to combine my two passions, Fashion Design and Custom Tailoring. Everyone wants to look their best and having a wardrobe curated to your body and lifestyle not only enables you to look your best but makes you feel your best.
                    At The Tailory New York, “we believe that your wardrobe should not only fit perfectly, but should be designed with only YOU in mind.” Providing personally designed, fitted and curated collections for each individual client is the essence of who we are. Let us curate and design the wardrobe fit for YOU! </br>
                    <br> </br>
                    Sincerely,</br>
                    Shao Yang, Founder 
                    <br> </br>
                </p> 
        </div>
```

and the css is:

```
h2{
    margin: 0 0 1.2em 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: normal;
}

.about_content{
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

.about_content img{
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: left;
}
.about_content p: last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have now will cause the content to wrap around the image. The trick to doing this is applying `float: left;` to the image, which you have already done.

What I'm suspecting is happening is your image is too wide. If it's 500px or wider, the image will take up the entire width of `.about_content`, so you need to limit the size of the image. Here's an example utilizing `max-width` on the image.

```css
h2{
    margin: 0 0 1.2em 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: normal;
}

.about_content{
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

.about_content img{
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: left;
  max-width: 250px;
}
.about_content p: last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="about_content">
            <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/541ff355e4b03f1e8815bc58/t/54b43e30e4b0ad2aad39a7f2/1421098552235/budak?format=500w" alt="">
            <h2>The Brand</h2>
            </p>
            The Tailory New York is an appointment only custom clothing              company that combines the modernity of Fashion Design with the heritage art of Custom Tailoring. We are unique in that we cater to both the Men and Women market.
           </p>
            <h2>The Concept </h2>
                <p>
                    Providing personally designed, fitted and curated collections for each individual client is the essence of who we are. At The Tailory New York, we believe that your wardrobe should not only fit perfectly, but should be designed with only YOU in mind. The end result?—clients get the best of both worlds, impeccable custom fit and custom designed pieces that works seamlessly with their lifestyle.
                </p>
            <h2>A Note From the Founder</h2>
                <p>
                    The idea for The Tailory New York began when I decided to direct my years of fashion design and men’s tailoring experience towards my own wardrobe. As a pant suit aficionado and a lover of men’s fashion and tailoring, I was always drawn to tailored clothing and strived to create fashion that conveyed the same message of confidence that a perfectly custom tailored suit did for men. Style icons like Sean Connery and Cary Grant, as well as modern day 007 Daniel Craig (shaken not stirred) were always my style inspirations. To me, they are the epitome of refinement and sophistication, true gentlemen in style.
                    My passion for fashion and tailoring led me through the Fashion Design program at Parsons followed by stints in custom tailoring, fashion design, fashion styling and brand development. But the more I integrated myself in the industry, the more I realized that impeccable fit, for men and women, was almost impossible to find in ready to wear clothing. So, I launched The Tailory New York, a way for me to combine my two passions, Fashion Design and Custom Tailoring. Everyone wants to look their best and having a wardrobe curated to your body and lifestyle not only enables you to look your best but makes you feel your best.
                    At The Tailory New York, “we believe that your wardrobe should not only fit perfectly, but should be designed with only YOU in mind.” Providing personally designed, fitted and curated collections for each individual client is the essence of who we are. Let us curate and design the wardrobe fit for YOU! </br>
                    <br> </br>
                    Sincerely,</br>
                    Shao Yang, Founder 
                    <br> </br>
                </p> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks a lot! it worked for me! A follow up question, how do I change the distance between the texts and the picture? Like, I wanna drag the texts away from the picture and kind of be in an invisible box?

Comment: @Catherine sweet, no problem. To put some space between the image and text, apply margin to `.about_content img`. Not sure what you mean by an invisible box.